# TYPO3 extension install with the composer

Tags: composer-php, typo3

I'm trying to install extension via composer, but I get the following error log:

```
Using version ^6.0 for georgringer/news
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package minimum-stability could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for georgringer/news ^6.0 -> satisfiable by georgringer/news[6.0.0].
    - georgringer/news 6.0.0 requires typo3/cms-core ^7.6.13 || >=8.5.0 <9 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

my guess is that require-dev has to be changed to something else, but no idea what exactly. That's how my composer.json file looks:

```
{
    "name": "typo3/cms",
    "description": "TYPO3 CMS is a free open source Content Management Framework initially created by Kasper Skaarhoj and licensed under GNU/GPL.",
    "keywords": ["typo3", "cms", "content management system", "extbase"],
    "homepage": "https://typo3.org/",
    "type": "typo3-cms-core",
    "license": "GPL-2.0+",
    "authors": [{
            "name": "TYPO3 CMS Core Team",
            "role": "Developer",
            "homepage": "https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core"
        },
        {
            "name": "The TYPO3 Community",
            "role": "Contributor",
            "homepage": "https://typo3.org/community/"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "general": "https://typo3.org/support/",
        "issues": "https://forge.typo3.org",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/#typo3-cms",
        "news": "nntp://lists.typo3.org"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-pcre": "*",
        "ext-session": "*",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "psr/log": "~1.0.0",
        "pear/http_request2": "~2.3.0",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "~5.4.5",
        "symfony/console": "^2.7",
        "symfony/finder": "^2.7",
        "doctrine/instantiator": "~1.0.4",
        "typo3/class-alias-loader": "^1.0",
        "typo3/cms-composer-installers": "^1.2.8",
        "psr/http-message": "~1.0",
        "cogpowered/finediff": "~0.3.1",
        "mso/idna-convert": "^0.9.1"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8.0",
        "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.6.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.0"

    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-gd": "GDlib/Freetype is required for building images with text (GIFBUILDER) and can also be used to scale images",
        "ext-fileinfo": "Used for proper file type detection in the file abstraction layer",
        "ext-zlib": "TYPO3 uses zlib for amongst others output compression and un/packing t3x extension files",
        "ext-openssl": "",
        "ext-soap": "",
        "ext-zip": "",
        "ext-mysqli": ""
    },
    "extra": {
        "typo3/class-alias-loader": {
            "always-add-alias-loader": true
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-TYPO3_7-6": "7.x-dev"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "typo3/cms-about": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-aboutmodules": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-adodb": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-backend": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-context-help": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-core": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-cshmanual": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-css-styled-content": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-dbal": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-documentation": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-extbase": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-extensionmanager": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-feedit": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-felogin": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-filelist": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-filemetadata": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-fluid": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-form": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-frontend": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-func": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-func-wizards": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-indexed-search": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-indexed-search-mysql": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-info": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-info-pagetsconfig": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-install": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-lang": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-linkvalidator": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-lowlevel": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-opendocs": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-recordlist": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-recycler": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-reports": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-rsaauth": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-rtehtmlarea": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-saltedpasswords": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-scheduler": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-sv": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-sys-action": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-t3editor": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-t3skin": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-taskcenter": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-version": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-wizard-crpages": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-wizard-sortpages": "self.version",
        "typo3/cms-workspaces": "self.version"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\About\\": "typo3/sysext/about/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Aboutmodules\\": "typo3/sysext/aboutmodules/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\": "typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Belog\\": "typo3/sysext/belog/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Beuser\\": "typo3/sysext/beuser/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\ContextHelp\\": "typo3/sysext/context_help/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\": "typo3/sysext/core/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Cshmanual\\": "typo3/sysext/cshmanual/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\CssStyledContent\\": "typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Dbal\\": "typo3/sysext/dbal/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Documentation\\": "typo3/sysext/documentation/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\": "typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Extensionmanager\\": "typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Feedit\\": "typo3/sysext/feedit/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Felogin\\": "typo3/sysext/felogin/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Filelist\\": "typo3/sysext/filelist/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\": "typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\FluidStyledContent\\": "typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Form\\": "typo3/sysext/form/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\": "typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Func\\": "typo3/sysext/func/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Impexp\\": "typo3/sysext/impexp/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\IndexedSearch\\": "typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\IndexedSearchMysql\\": "typo3/sysext/indexed_search_mysql/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Info\\": "typo3/sysext/info/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\InfoPagetsconfig\\": "typo3/sysext/info_pagetsconfig/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Install\\": "typo3/sysext/install/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Lang\\": "typo3/sysext/lang/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Linkvalidator\\": "typo3/sysext/linkvalidator/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Lowlevel\\": "typo3/sysext/lowlevel/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Opendocs\\": "typo3/sysext/opendocs/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Recordlist\\": "typo3/sysext/recordlist/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Recycler\\": "typo3/sysext/recycler/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Reports\\": "typo3/sysext/reports/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Rsaauth\\": "typo3/sysext/rsaauth/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Rtehtmlarea\\": "typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Saltedpasswords\\": "typo3/sysext/saltedpasswords/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Scheduler\\": "typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Setup\\": "typo3/sysext/setup/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Sv\\": "typo3/sysext/sv/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\SysAction\\": "typo3/sysext/sys_action/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\SysNote\\": "typo3/sysext/sys_note/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\T3editor\\": "typo3/sysext/t3editor/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Taskcenter\\": "typo3/sysext/taskcenter/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Tstemplate\\": "typo3/sysext/tstemplate/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Version\\": "typo3/sysext/version/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Viewpage\\": "typo3/sysext/viewpage/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\WizardCrpages\\": "typo3/sysext/wizard_crpages/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\WizardSortpages\\": "typo3/sysext/wizard_sortpages/Classes/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Workspaces\\": "typo3/sysext/workspaces/Classes/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "typo3/sysext/core/Resources/PHP/",
            "typo3/sysext/fluid/Resources/PHP/"
        ],
        "files": [
            "typo3/sysext/core/Resources/PHP/GlobalDebugFunctions.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/backend/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Belog\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/belog/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Beuser\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/beuser/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/core/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Dbal\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/dbal/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Documentation\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/documentation/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/extbase/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Extensionmanager\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Felogin\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/felogin/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/fluid/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Form\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/form/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/frontend/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Impexp\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/impexp/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\IndexedSearch\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Install\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/install/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Lang\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/lang/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Lowlevel\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/lowlevel/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Recordlist\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/recordlist/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Reports\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/reports/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Rsaauth\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/rsaauth/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Saltedpasswords\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/saltedpasswords/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Scheduler\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/scheduler/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Sv\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/sv/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Workspaces\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/workspaces/Tests/",
            "TYPO3\\CMS\\Recycler\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/recycler/Tests/"
        },
        "classmap": ["typo3/sysext/extbase/Tests/Unit/Object/Container/Fixtures/"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should *never* use the `typo3/cms` package for running sites, create your own distribution instead and do `composer require typo3/cms` to add TYPO3. Among others this allows you to finely tune what packages and settings are used.

Here is an [distribution example](https://github.com/helhum/TYPO3-Distribution) to help you get started. Also see [TYPO3 and Composer](https://usetypo3.com/typo3-and-composer.html) for a general introduction.

The issue at hand is that Composer cannot determine the version of the `typo3/cms` package. You could work around this by setting the [`COMPOSER_ROOT_VERSION`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-root-version) environment variable:

```
export COMPOSER_ROOT_VERSION=X.Y.Z
```

But again, you should use your own distribution instead.

Comment: How and where do I set this COMPOSER_ROOT_VERSION variable? Creating my own distribution in my case is not an option.

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add

`"typo3/cms": "~7.6",`

to your **require/require-dev** options, so the news package should find a matching typo version.
The error u receive is simple: the news-package cant find a version for typo in the composer file.

NOTE: For an cleaner working dir you can configure how/where the basic package(typo3) should be saved with the extra-config block

**EDIT:**
the new composer.json file

```
{
  "name": "typo3/cms",
  "description": "TYPO3 CMS is a free open source Content Management Framework initially created by Kasper Skaarhoj and licensed under GNU/GPL.",
  "keywords": ["typo3", "cms", "content management system", "extbase"],
  "homepage": "https://typo3.org/",
  "type": "typo3-cms-core",
  "license": "GPL-2.0+",
  "authors": [{
    "name": "TYPO3 CMS Core Team",
    "role": "Developer",
    "homepage": "https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core"
  },
    {
      "name": "The TYPO3 Community",
      "role": "Contributor",
      "homepage": "https://typo3.org/community/    "
    }
  ],
  "support": {
    "general": "https://typo3.org/support/",
    "issues": "https://forge.typo3.org",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/#typo3-cms",
    "news": "nntp://lists.typo3.org"
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "bin-dir": "bin"
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.0",
    "typo3/cms": "*",
    "georgringer/news": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-pcre": "*",
    "ext-session": "*",
    "ext-xml": "*",
    "psr/log": "~1.0.0",
    "pear/http_request2": "*",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "~5.4.5",
    "symfony/console": "^2.7",
    "symfony/finder": "^2.7",
    "doctrine/instantiator": "~1.0.4",
    "typo3/class-alias-loader": "^1.0",
    "typo3/cms-composer-installers": "^1.2.8",
    "psr/http-message": "~1.0",
    "cogpowered/finediff": "~0.3.1",
    "mso/idna-convert": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8.0",
    "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.6.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.0"
  },
  "suggest": {
    "ext-gd": "GDlib/Freetype is required for building images with text (GIFBUILDER) and can also be used to scale images",
    "ext-fileinfo": "Used for proper file type detection in the file abstraction layer",
    "ext-zlib": "TYPO3 uses zlib for amongst others output compression and un/packing t3x extension files",
    "ext-openssl": "",
    "ext-soap": "",
    "ext-zip": "",
    "ext-mysqli": ""
  },
  "extra": {
    "typo3/class-alias-loader": {
      "always-add-alias-loader": true
    },
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-TYPO3_7-6": "7.x-dev"
    }
  },
  "replace": {
    "typo3/cms-about": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-aboutmodules": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-adodb": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-backend": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-belog": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-beuser": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-context-help": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-core": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-cshmanual": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-css-styled-content": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-dbal": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-documentation": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-extbase": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-extensionmanager": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-feedit": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-felogin": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-filelist": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-filemetadata": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-fluid": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-form": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-frontend": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-func": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-func-wizards": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-impexp": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-indexed-search": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-indexed-search-mysql": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-info": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-info-pagetsconfig": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-install": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-lang": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-linkvalidator": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-lowlevel": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-opendocs": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-recordlist": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-recycler": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-reports": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-rsaauth": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-rtehtmlarea": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-saltedpasswords": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-scheduler": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-setup": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-sv": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-sys-action": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-sys-note": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-t3editor": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-t3skin": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-taskcenter": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-version": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-viewpage": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-wizard-crpages": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-wizard-sortpages": "self.version",
    "typo3/cms-workspaces": "self.version"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\About\\": "typo3/sysext/about/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Aboutmodules\\": "typo3/sysext/aboutmodules/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\": "typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Belog\\": "typo3/sysext/belog/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Beuser\\": "typo3/sysext/beuser/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\ContextHelp\\": "typo3/sysext/context_help/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\": "typo3/sysext/core/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Cshmanual\\": "typo3/sysext/cshmanual/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\CssStyledContent\\": "typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Dbal\\": "typo3/sysext/dbal/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Documentation\\": "typo3/sysext/documentation/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\": "typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Extensionmanager\\": "typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Feedit\\": "typo3/sysext/feedit/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Felogin\\": "typo3/sysext/felogin/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Filelist\\": "typo3/sysext/filelist/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\": "typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\FluidStyledContent\\": "typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Form\\": "typo3/sysext/form/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\": "typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Func\\": "typo3/sysext/func/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Impexp\\": "typo3/sysext/impexp/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\IndexedSearch\\": "typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\IndexedSearchMysql\\": "typo3/sysext/indexed_search_mysql/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Info\\": "typo3/sysext/info/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\InfoPagetsconfig\\": "typo3/sysext/info_pagetsconfig/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Install\\": "typo3/sysext/install/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Lang\\": "typo3/sysext/lang/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Linkvalidator\\": "typo3/sysext/linkvalidator/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Lowlevel\\": "typo3/sysext/lowlevel/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Opendocs\\": "typo3/sysext/opendocs/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Recordlist\\": "typo3/sysext/recordlist/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Recycler\\": "typo3/sysext/recycler/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Reports\\": "typo3/sysext/reports/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Rsaauth\\": "typo3/sysext/rsaauth/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Rtehtmlarea\\": "typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Saltedpasswords\\": "typo3/sysext/saltedpasswords/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Scheduler\\": "typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Setup\\": "typo3/sysext/setup/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Sv\\": "typo3/sysext/sv/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\SysAction\\": "typo3/sysext/sys_action/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\SysNote\\": "typo3/sysext/sys_note/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\T3editor\\": "typo3/sysext/t3editor/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Taskcenter\\": "typo3/sysext/taskcenter/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Tstemplate\\": "typo3/sysext/tstemplate/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Version\\": "typo3/sysext/version/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Viewpage\\": "typo3/sysext/viewpage/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\WizardCrpages\\": "typo3/sysext/wizard_crpages/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\WizardSortpages\\": "typo3/sysext/wizard_sortpages/Classes/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Workspaces\\": "typo3/sysext/workspaces/Classes/"
    },
    "classmap": [
      "typo3/sysext/core/Resources/PHP/",
      "typo3/sysext/fluid/Resources/PHP/"
    ],
    "files": [
      "typo3/sysext/core/Resources/PHP/GlobalDebugFunctions.php"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/backend/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Belog\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/belog/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Beuser\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/beuser/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/core/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Dbal\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/dbal/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Documentation\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/documentation/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/extbase/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Extensionmanager\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Felogin\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/felogin/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/fluid/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Form\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/form/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/frontend/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Impexp\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/impexp/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\IndexedSearch\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Install\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/install/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Lang\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/lang/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Lowlevel\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/lowlevel/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Recordlist\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/recordlist/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Reports\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/reports/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Rsaauth\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/rsaauth/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Saltedpasswords\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/saltedpasswords/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Scheduler\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/scheduler/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Sv\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/sv/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Workspaces\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/workspaces/Tests/",
      "TYPO3\\CMS\\Recycler\\Tests\\": "typo3/sysext/recycler/Tests/"
    },
    "classmap": ["typo3/sysext/extbase/Tests/Unit/Object/Container/Fixtures/"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I got:

**Problem 1**- The requested package typo3/cms No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by typo3/cms[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

**Problem 2**
    - The requested package typo3/cms (installed at No version set (parsed as 1.0.0), required as ~7.6) is satisfiable by typo3/cms[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: please try to replace "~7.6" with "*" and tell me if this works

Comment: If you fix:    
"typo3/cms": "*",
"georgringer/news": " * ",
"pear/http_request2": " * ",

the composer install works but fails after the installation on : friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer

The error migth be raised by the postinstall script of the package.
Do you need this package?
You can try without and it works.
Otherwise you have to check the versions of the packages. There migth be one or more with wrong versions.

Im sorry, that i cant provide you a better solution

Comment: How do I do it without current package? Maybe it looks like a dumb question, but I have 0 experience with the composer and everything related to it. And you've given some good help so far, so nothing to be sorry about.

Comment: Dont worry :) Just delete the composer.lock-file, add/replace the existing entries in your composer.json-file (in the require-block) with the following lines:

 "typo3/cms": "*", 

"georgringer/news": "*",

 "pear/http_request2": "*"

and run `composer install` afterwards

this should help. I will add your composer.json file (how it should look after the inserts) to my answer

Comment: There's no composer.lock file.

Comment: ok if there is composer.lock file, jsut ignore it. the composer.lock file will be written afterwards

Comment: Did like you said and got some exception at the end of an installation: http://i.imgur.com/JGtxZV5.png 

And news extension still didn't get installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149590/discussion-between-zenia-bogdasic-and-unherz).